# RISC-V build 32-bit constants with LUI and ADDI

Tags: assembly, constants, riscv, immediate-operand

> LUI (load upper immediate) is used to build 32-bit constants and uses the U-type format. LUI places the U-immediate value in the top 20 bits of the destination register rd, filling in the lowest 12 bits with zeros.

I found this in manual, but if I want to move 0xffffffff to a register, all the code I need is:

```
LUI x2, 0xfffff000
ADDI x2, x2, 0xfff
```

But a problem occurred, ADDI will extend sign to make a immediate data to a signed number, so `0xfff` will be extend to `0xffffffff`.

It make `x2` to `0xffffefff` but not `0xffffffff`

and what is an good implementation to move a 32bits immediate to register?

Answer (score 22):

TL;DR: The 32-bit constant you want to load into `x2` is `0xffffffff` which corresponds to *-1*. Since *-1* is in the range *[-2048, 2047]*, this constant can be loaded with a single instruction: `addi x2, zero, -1`. You can also use the `li` pseudoinstruction: `li, x2, -1` which the assembler, in turn, translates to `addi x2, zero, -1`.

#### Loading a 32-bit constant with a `lui`+`addi` sequence

In general, we need a `lui`+`addi` sequence – two instructions – for loading a 32-bit constant into a register. The `lui` instruction encodes a 20-bit immediate, whereas the `addi` instruction encodes a 12-bit immediate. `lui` and `addi` can be used to load the upper 20 bits and the lower 12 bits of a 32-bit constant, respectively.

Let *N* be a 32-bit constant we want to load into a register: *N ≡ n<sub>31</sub> ... n<sub>0</sub>*. Then, we can split this constant into its upper 20 bits and lower 12 bits, *N<sub>U</sub>* and *N<sub>L</sub>*, respectively: *N<sub>U</sub> ≡ n<sub>31</sub> ... n<sub>12</sub>* ; *N<sub>L</sub> ≡ n<sub>11</sub> ... n<sub>0</sub>*

In principle, we encode *N<sub>U</sub>* in the immediate in `lui` and *N<sub>L</sub>* in the immediate in `addi`. Nevertheless, there is a difficulty to handle **if the most significant bit of the 12-bit immediate in `addi` is *1*** because the immediate value encoded in the `addi` instruction is ***sign extended*** to 32 bits. If this is the case, the `addi` instruction adds to the destination register not *N<sub>L</sub>*, but ***N<sub>L</sub> - 4096*** instead — *-4096* (or -2<sup>12</sup>) is the resulting number when the upper 20 bits are *1*s and the lower 12 bits are *0*s.

To compensate for the unwanted term *-4096*, we can add *1* to `lui`'s immediate – the LSB of the immediate in `lui` corresponds to bit *#12* – so, adding *1* to this immediate results in adding *4096* to the destination register which cancels out the *-4096* term.

#### Loading a 32-bit constant with a single `addi` instruction

The issue explained above is due to the sign extension that the immediate in `addi` undergoes. The decision of sign extending `addi`'s immediate was probably to allow the loading of *small integers* – **integers between *-2048* and *2047*, both inclusive – with a single `addi` instruction**. For example, if the immediate in `addi` were *zero extended* instead of sign extended, it wouldn't be possible to load such a frequent constant like *-1* into a register with just a single instruction.

---

#### Loading a 32-bit constant with the `li` *pseudoinstruction*

In any case, you can always use the `li` pseudoinstruction for loading a 32-bit constant without having to care about what the value of the constant to load is. This pseudoinstruction can load any 32-bit number into a register, and it is, therefore, simpler to use and less error-prone than manually writing the `lui`+`addi` sequence.

If the number fits in `addi`'s immediate field (*[-2048, 2047]*), the assembler will translate the `li` pseudoinstruction into just an `addi` instruction, otherwise, `li` will be translated into a `lui`+`addi` sequence and the complication explained above is handled automatically by the assembler.

Answer (score 9):

The RISC-V assembler supports the pseudo-instruction `li x2, 0xFFFFFFFF`.

Let `N`is a signed, 2's complement 32 bit integer.

Common case implementation of `li x2,N` is:

```
    # sign extend low 12 bits
    M=(N << 20) >> 20

    # Upper 20 bits
    K=((N-M) >> 12) <<12

    # Load upper 20 bits
    LUI x2,K

    # Add lower bits
    ADDI x2,x2,M
```

Of course, to load short immediate `li` can use

```
   addi x2,x0,imm
```

So, `li x2, 0xFFFFFFFF` is `addi x2,x0,-1`.

Comment: By the way, if anyone is wondering where this stuff is documented, it's in the RISC-V Assembly Programmer's Manual: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-asm-manual/blob/master/riscv-asm.md

Answer (score 7):

I was going to say "use `ORI` instead of `ADDI`" but then I read the Instruction Set Manual and it turns out that that doesn't work either, because all of the lower-12 Immediate operands get sign-extended, even for logical operations.

AFAICT you have to bias the value you put into the upper 20 bits in a way that anticipates the effect of the instruction you use to set the lower 12 bits.  So if you want to end up with a value X in the top 20 bits and you're going to use `ADDI` to set the lower 12 bits, and those lower 12 bits have a 1 in the leftmost position, you must do `LUI (X+1)` rather than `LUI X`.  Similarly if you are going to use `XORI` to set the lower 12 bits, and those lower 12 bits have a 1 in the leftmost position, you must do `LUI (~X)` (that is, the bitwise inverse of X) rather than `LUI X`.

But before you do any of that, I'd look to see whether your assembler already has some sort of "load immediate" pseudo-op or macro that will take care of this for you.  If it doesn't, then see if you can write one :-)

It's not unusual for RISC processors to need this kind of extra effort from the programmer (or, more usually, from the compiler).  The idea is "keep the hardware simple so it can go fast, and it doesn't matter if that makes it harder to construct the software".

Comment: You were thinking of MIPS.  MIPS zero-extends bitwise boolean immediates (`ori` / `andi` / `xori`), allowing a value-range from 0..65535 to be created with `ori $rd, $zero, imm16`, vs. `-32768 .. 32767` for `addiu`.  (MIPS spends more instruction-coding space on wide immediates for I-type instructions.  RISC-V just has 20-bit LUI / AUIPC and narrower I-type instructions).

Comment: Anyway, most assemblers for RISC-V (or at least GAS / clang) have `%lo` and `%hi` "macros" so you can `lui dst, %hi(value)` / `addi dst, dst, %lo(value)`.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, just use an `li` pseudo-instruction that gets the assembler to optimize to one instruction if possible (a single lui or a single addi), and if not does the math for you.

```
   li    t0, 0x12345678
   li    t1, 123
   li    t2, -1
   li    t3, 0xffffffff    # same as -1 in 32-bit 2's complement
   li    t4, 1<<17
```

I separated each "group" with spaces.  Only the first one (into `t0`) needed two instructions.

```
$ clang -c -target riscv32 rv.s         # on my x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux desktop
$ llvm-objdump -d rv.o
...
00000000 <.text>:
       0: 01 00         nop
       2: 01 00         nop

       4: b7 52 34 12   lui     t0, 74565
       8: 93 82 82 67   addi    t0, t0, 1656

       c: 13 03 b0 07   addi    t1, zero, 123

      10: fd 53         addi    t2, zero, -1

      12: 7d 5e         addi    t3, zero, -1

      14: b7 0e 02 00   lui     t4, 32
```

If you *do* want to do it manually, most assemblers for RISC-V (or at least GAS / clang) have `%lo` and `%hi` "macros" so you can `lui dst, %hi(value)` / `addi dst, dst, %lo(value)`.

```
   lui   x9, %hi(0x12345678)
   addi  x9, x9, %lo(0x12345678)

   lui   x10, %hi(0xFFFFFFFF)
   addi  x10, x10, %lo(0xFFFFFFFF)
```

assemble with clang, disassemble with llvm-objdump again:

```
      18: b7 54 34 12   lui     s1, 74565
      1c: 93 84 84 67   addi    s1, s1, 1656

      20: 37 05 00 00   lui     a0, 0
      24: 7d 15         addi    a0, a0, -1
```

Note that `lui a0, 0` is a silly waste of an instruction that results from naively using hi/lo on 0xffffffff without realizing that the whole thing fits in a sign-extended 12-bit immediate.

---

**There are good use-cases for manual %hi/%lo, especially for addresses,** where you have one aligned "anchor" point and want to load or store to some label after that:

```
   lui   t0, %hi(symbol)

   lw    t1, %lo(symbol)(t0)
   lw    t2, %lo(symbol2)(t0)
   addi  t3, t0, %lo(symbol3)   # also put an address in a register
   ...
   sw    t1, %lo(symbol)(t0)
```

So instead of wasting instructions doing a separate lui for each symbol, if you know they're in the same 2k aligned block you can reference them all relative to one base with the assembler's help.  Or actually to a 4k aligned block with the "anchor" in the middle, since `%lo` can be negative.

(**The PC-relative version of this with `auipc` is just as efficient** but looks a little different: [What do %pcrel_hi and %pcrel_lo actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879012/what-do-pcrel-hi-and-pcrel-lo-actually-do) - %pcrel_lo actually references a %pcrel_hi relocation to find out the actual target symbol as well as the location of the relative reference.)