# What is this "Myriad sequences"? (What li gets expanded to?)

Tags: assembly, riscv

In the RISC-V unprivileged manual, it wrote that there is this pseudoinstruction called `li`:

```
li rd, immediate     | Myriad sequences               | Load immediate
```

But it only says that the Base Instruction is `Myriad sequences`, which, after googling, gives no promising answer of what it is.

Does anyone know what `Myriad sequences` is and what `li` get expanded to?

Also after playing a while with godbolt, I see that making the follwing function:

```c
int func(void) {
    return 0x12345LL;
}
```

Gives the asm output (With `-O2` flag):

```
func:
        li      a0,73728
        addi    a0,a0,837
        ret
```

But if I tick the `compile to binary` option, godbolt gives me

```
main:
 lui    a0,0x12
 addi   a0,a0,837 # 12345 <__BSS_END__+0x30d>
 ret
```

Does this mean that `li` get expaned to `addi`? Or was it the linker doing some optimizations?

Comment: No, in this case the `li` got changed into the `lui` since `73728` is `0x12000`. Normally you'd expect the compiler (or the programmer) to just write `li a0, 0x12345` and let the assembler figure it all out, which would then produce the same two instructions from a single `li` directly.

Comment: For the number 0x12345. the combination of `lui` + `addi` are the expansion of `li` — it is a 2:1 *expansion* (2 machine code instructions for 1 line of assembly).  It is not always necessary to expand, however, often a simple 1:1 translation is possible.  For example, if the constant is small it will become simply an `addi`, and if it is a multiple of 0x1000, then `lui` alone can handle it.  There's no specification of the expansion for every integer, so the manual just says myriad.. (also, there's really no need for a spec: if you have a preferred sequence, use it instead of `li`).

Comment: `lui` + `addi` can only form 32-bit constants, so for even larger `LL`s the compiler may generate 3 or more instructions.  We have sometimes seen the compilers generate working but suboptimal sequences as well for very large constants.  These can be reported as missing optimizations.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59546567

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're programming in assembly or a compiler writer generating assembly code, you can choose to use the `li` pseudo instruction or avoid it, as you like.

For 32-bit integers, it will generate some combination of `lui` + `addi`, though either one may be omitted depending on the constant's value.

- If the immediate value given  to `li` is small and can fit in signed 12-bit field, an `addi` alone will suffice, though the assembler would not be remiss in using `ori` instead.
- If the immediate value given to `li` is a multiple of 0x1000 then `lui` alone can handle the job as well.

For constants larger than 32 bits, the choice of sequence can be 3 or more instructions.  We have seen compilers generate working but suboptimal code sequences for certain large constants.

There is a trade off here between number of registers used to construct a large immediate and the number of instructions needed to do so — sometimes using an extra register can shorten the code sequence, reusing an intermediate value.  Other optimizations are possible as well, such as reusing (as in common subexpression elimination or loop invariant code motion) an intermediate value to be used in generation of two separate larger immediates.

However, while the option of using more registers so as to use fewer instructions is  available to compilers and assembly programmers (since they are aware of other register usage in the compilation) this trade off is not available to assemblers themselves as they don't track register usages within or between functions.  Assemblers are thus limited to using one scratch register, namely the target of the `li` as a temporary to construct the constant.

Many clever sequences are possible to construct an immediate.  An `addi` followed by a shift left may be appropriate for constants that are 12 non-zero bits or less but have zero bits as LSBs (even though the `lui` + `addi` at the same instruction length will work as well).  These sequence variations become more relevant for larger (>32 bit) constant values.

There's no consumer need for the assembler to use a well-defined sequence to generate the immediate, so the RISC V specification omits any specification and defers to the assembler implementation.

In fact, the RISC V specification goes beyond most ISA specs in rolling into (and standardizing) the specifications of many useful pseudo instructions like `ret` and `call` that are not really part of the ISA literally, but do help both with assembly programming as well as facilitation of hardware optimization like shadow call stack, via helping to cement certain conventions.

---

The `lui` + `addi` sequence has some oddities as follows: the `addi` uses a 12-bit signed immediate, which means that in order to construct a 32-bit immediate that has the 12th bit set, the constant provided to the `lui` must be biased by +1 !  This is because the 12-bit immediate from the `addi` will sign extend and become negative so the bias of +1 in the `lui` is needed.

One might ask why did the RISC V designers use `addi` that sign extends?

For background let's note that MIPS designers chose two forms of sign extension, signed for `addi` and unsigned/zero for `ori`.  So for certain sequences MIPS could avoid the +1/-1 issue.  However, they also wanted to be able to put the lower part of the immediate into the offset available in `lw` and `sw`, and these have sign extending immediates (which is desirable for other reasons).  So all the machinery needed to use immediates in `lui` + `lw` is needed anyway, meaning the bias of `lui` by +1 in certain cases.

RISC V embraces this — even eliminated the zero extending immediates altogether to simplify decoding — so they must contend with the +1/-1 biasing for all `lui` + ... combinations anyway.

Answer (score 3):

"Myriad sequences" isn't a specific technical term.

It's an English phrase meaning that assemblers have a choice of many different ways of expanding `li` (depending on the constant and the strategy they choose), and all of them are allowed as long as they get the same result.

You won't find anything useful from searching for "myriad sequences"; the right approach in this case is to look up "myriad" in a dictionary if you aren't familiar with its meaning as an English word: [google for `define myriad`](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20myriad) pulls a definition from the Oxford Engish dictionary:

> *adjective*
> countless or extremely great in number.
> e.g. "the myriad lights of the city"

---

In your example, `li  a0,73728` obviously expanded to `lui a0, 0x12`, since the constant `73728` is `0x12000`.
The `addi` was already present in the asm source, and thus appears literally in the machine code.

More normally a human would write `li a0, 0x12345` and let an assembler expand it to `lui`+`addi`, but the compiler you picked seemed to be using `li` just for the `lui` part of materializing a constant.