# Preventing direct encoding from taking up the full encoding space for custom cpu architecture

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture

I am currently creating a CPU architecture as a hobby, and am writing an assembler in Python. I've chosen to directly encode the instruction, registers, and immediate values because it's easier at the moment. However, an issue I believe can happen is that if the fixed size is 64 bits and the intermediate value I am encoding is also 64 bits, there won't be any space for either of them. Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: The usual trick is to have separate instructions for loading the low and high parts of the register.

Comment: Look at how other architectures deal with this problem and copy their approaches.  You'll find that the same problem exists with any sort of immediate operand.  You'll have to pick some shorter immediate size and accept that some immediates won't fit or extend your instruction word in length so they'll always fit.

Comment: No, there is no way to pack 64 bits (e.g. an immediate) plus something else (e.g. an opcode of 6 bits, maybe a register field or two) into one 64-bit instruction!  Either employ variable length instructions or split the content into multiple instructions, or both.  If you split into multiple instructions, you'll either loose some bits to repetition,  or have implicit targets/sources (e.g. condition codes).

Comment: [RISC-V build 32-bit constants with LUI and ADDI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50742420) is a good look at how a typical RISC handles it, what Jester was talking about.  (With 32-bit instruction length, building 64-bit constants is rather involved; look at RV64 compiler output for `return `0x123456789abcd` on https://godbolt.org/ for example, vs. how x86-64 does it with one 10-byte instruction.  But if you're planning to have 64-bit instruction size, the 2-halves strategy works).

Comment: AArch64 has a design that's nice for hardware, with bit-range / bit-pattern immediates for bitwise boolean instructions, so for example `and x0, x1, 0x5555555555555555` is encodeable because it's the same pattern repeated across the whole constant.  But that's complexity (in the decoders and assembler) you don't need in a hobby project; just force software to use multiple instructions like most non-ARM architectures.